# Arboreal Grazer

Tags: magic-the-gathering

hi i have a doubt with the next card thats cames on the next set:

[image]

can i put a shokland into the battlefield pay the 2 lifes and get the land untaped like withc Growth Spiral?
I think is like the same efect that the land enter the battlefield taped and then you have the option to choose.